# Migrate Subversion Dump to Mac-Friendly Version Control System

Tags: macos, version-control

First, some background. I had a Mac Mini which was (amongst other things) a Subversion server. It was working great, and I was using the Versions.app client to connect to it (from a Mac Pro and MacBook Pro, all on OS 10.8) and version control some projects.

I had my modem configured to route the relevant ports to the Mac mini, meaning I could still access it even when away from the office.

Then I upgraded to OS 10.8 and discovered too late that the subversion server won't work any more, at least not without a lot of messing around. I dumped the repository to a svn .dmp file and started looking for alternatives:

- Installing a subversion module on my NAS failed to work (apparently due to a fault with the module)
- Looking for a Mac OS 10.8-compatible subversion server resulted in a few dead ends
- Trying to find a pre-configured virtual machine to use in Parallels hasn't been successful

Apple seem to be pushing GIT, so that seems like a good alternative, particularly as it seems to mean (assuming I'm understanding it correctly) I would no longer need to have a single "master" server. However, I still have the same issues, namely that there doesn't seem to be much in the way of a simple, clean way to get a Git server up and running on OS X.

At this point, I'm even prepared to just lose all the "historic" data from the previous version control system and just start with a new commit of the current state of everything, but I'm still not finding a good Mac-friendly system with which to do so.

Comment: EDIT: You're pushing a product that you sell? Classy.

Comment: The product is provided by the company I'm working for. Just for your reference. :)